# apache won't start up

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd

we just got through a power outage. All our servers came back up properly, except out web server gives me this error when attempting to start apache:

```
# apachectl start
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I've verified that there are no processes using the port apache is configured to listen on, and I can't fine apache running in ps aux. Does anyone have any suggestions for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem - sorry the answer is so late in coming, things are really busy here. Thanks for all your help!

The problem was that this server has a special setup, and I needed to pass apachectl the -d SSL option for it to start.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 DNS servers, can you check in your /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 then try to start the services

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the line in /etc/hosts that starts with 127.0.0.1 is '127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.my.domain'

Comment: I should note that this server has been running without issue for several years, and nothing has changed on it for the past couple months.

Comment: i m asking do you have 127.0.0.1 entry at hosts file or yours DNS entry suppose if you have config johnb.com that is redirected to 127.0.0.1

Comment: but right now its not work you said

Comment: no, I just have the 127.0.0.1 entry in /etc/hosts the way I wrote it in my first comment.

Comment: i'm sorry i didnt understood that then it has to start your apache2 server

Answer (score 0):

Is anything else listening on port 80?  netstat -nlt show anything else on 80?

Has servername changed and/or resolv.conf not able to do a reverse lookup on starting up apache.

Does hostname -f resolve properly?

Answer (score 0):

Apache won't start if it can't log.  The second line, 
`Unable to open logs`,  jumps out at me more so than the first.

Check to make sure that there's enough disk space for the path which you are logging.

`df -H`

Also, verify permissions for the logging directory and files.

`ls -al /var/log/httpd`